# How can I format these data sets nicely in a table?

Tags: plotting, data, grid-layouts

I have three data sets, each generated by `Table` in the following manner:

```
data1 = Table[f[n],{n,1,10}];
data2 = Table[g[n],{n,1,10}];
data3 = Table[h[n],{n,1,10}];
```

I would like to generate a nice looking table with these results in the following style:

```
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
|  n  |    Col1    |    Col2    |    Col3    |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
|   1 | data1[[1]] | data2[[1]] | data3[[1]] |
|   2 | data1[[2]] | data2[[2]] | data3[[2]] |
| ... |            |            |            |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
```

How can I do so, without modifying my code for generating the tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Grid[Prepend[MapIndexed[Join[#2, #1] &, Transpose[{data1, data2, data3}]],
             {"n", "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"}], 
     Dividers -> {{{True}}, {True, True}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: formatted table]

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thank you!